# Probability of a stock going up after randomly buying them at certain prices

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I've got a seemingly simple question.

If I'd randomly bought all kinds of stocks/securities at random points, what would be the probability of it going up within the first 30 minutes if we did it infinite amount of times?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you conduct a Monte Carlo simulation based on historical data?

Comment: does it go up and down evenly ? if not that may effect things.

Comment: It depends on your model.  But for a basic model there is a factor that is linear with time (i.e. "in the long-term stocks go up"), and there is a factor for noise.  $\Delta S = \mu t  + \sqrt t \Delta z$   When $t$ is small $ \sqrt t > t$ and the noise factor dominates.  If your noise normal (or just symmetric) prices are as likely to go up as down in the short-term, and you can't diversify that fact away.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee No, it's not like a sinus graph. Stock markets, like doug said, usually grow, thus go up.

Comment: @DougM How would that affect the probability? Unless extreme growth, how does that affect the probability?

Comment: I didn't say it was I was asking for more information as depending on what price it was at and the price changes it can also go bankrupt.

Comment: If we knew this for certain we would all be rich!